# How do I allow mock a locally scoped variable in a controller to receive a message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

So, I've only been doing Ruby for a couple of days. Any tips would be appreciated it.

variable.rb

```
class Variable < ApplicationRecord
  def some_attribute=(value)
    #do something with the vlue
  end
end
```

X_Controller.rb

```
class XController < ApplicationController
  def do_something
    variable = Variable.instance_with_id(params[:id])
    variable.some_attribute = some_new_value
    redirect_to(some_url)
  end
end
```

x_controller_spec.rb

```
describe '#do_something' do
  before do
    allow(Variable).to receive(:instance_with_id) # Works fine
    allow_any_instance_of(Variable).to receive(:some_attribute)
    
    post :do_something, :params => { id: 'uuid' }, :format => :json 
  end

  it { 
    expect(variable).to have_received(:some_attribute)
  }
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
let(:variable) { instance_double("Variable") }

before do
  allow(Variable).to receive(:instance_with_id).and_return(variable)
  allow(variable).to receive(:some_attribute=)

  # ...
end
```

Because `instance_with_id` should return something. And then you want to allow calling `some_attribute=`(note the `=`) on that instance.